# Shorter way of proving infinite series convergence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I tried to solve a particular problem of infinite series convergence and I think I got it right, but I feel like there's a shorter and nicer way of achieving the same result. The series in question is:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2n)!!e^n}{(2n-1)^{n+\frac{7}{4}}}
$$

Here's my attempt at it:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2n)!!e^n}{(2n-1)^{n+\frac{7}{4}}} =
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^nn!e^n}{(2n-1)^{n+\frac{7}{4}}}
$$

By limit comparison test:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^nn!e^n}{(2n-1)^{n+\frac{7}{4}}} \frac{(2n)^{n+\frac{7}{4}}}{2^nn!e^n} =
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{1}{2n} \right)^n} \left( \frac{2n}{2n - 1} \right)^{\frac{7}{4}} = \frac{1}{e^{-\frac{1}{2}}} = \sqrt{e}
$$

Now:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^nn!e^n}{(2n)^{n+\frac{7}{4}}} = \frac{1}{2^{\frac{7}{4}}} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n!e^n}{n^{n+\frac{7}{4}}}
$$

If $n$-th term of the series on the right is $a_n$, we have:
$$
\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} = \frac{1}{e} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n + \frac{7}{4}}
$$

Let $p := \lim_{n \to \infty} n \left( \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} - 1 \right)$. Then
$$
p = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n+1)^{n + \frac{7}{4}} - en^{n + \frac{7}{4}}}{en^{n + \frac{3}{4}}}
= \frac{1}{e} \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n + \frac{7}{4}} - e}{ \frac{1}{n} }
$$

By L'Hôpital's rule:
$$
p = \frac{1}{e} \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n + \frac{7}{4}} \left(\ln \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right) - \frac{4n+7}{4n(n+1)} \right) }{-\frac{1}{n^2}}
$$

Proof for numerator part. Let $y := \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n + \frac{7}{4}}$. Then
$$
\left(\ln y\right)' = \left(\left(n + \frac{7}{4}\right) \ln \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)\right)'
$$
$$
\frac{y}{y'} = \ln \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right) + \frac{n + \frac{7}{4}}{\frac{n+1}{n}} \left(-\frac{1}{n^2}\right) = \ln \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right) - \frac{4n+7}{4n(n+1)}
$$
$$
y' = \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n + \frac{7}{4}} \left(\ln \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right) - \frac{4n+7}{4n(n+1)} \right)
$$

Further analysis of $p$:
\begin{align*}
 p &= \frac{1}{e} \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n + \frac{7}{4}} \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ \ln \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right) - \frac{4n+7}{4n(n+1)} }{-\frac{1}{n^2}}
      = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ \ln \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right) - \frac{4n+7}{4n(n+1)} }{-\frac{1}{n^2}}\\
 &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4n^2+7n - (4n^3+4n^2)\ln \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)}{4n+4}
\end{align*}

Using L'Hôpital's rule again:
\begin{align*}
 p &= \frac{1}{4} \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 8n+7-(12n^2+8n)\ln \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right) - \frac{4n^2(n+1)n}{(n+1)n^2} \right)\\
 &= \frac{1}{4} \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 12n+7-(12n^2+8n)\ln \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right) \right)
\end{align*}

Replacing $\ln \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)$ with the first two terms of its Taylor series expansion gives:
\begin{align*}
 p &= \frac{1}{4} \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 12n+7-(12n^2+8n) \left( \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{2n^2} \right) \right)\\
 &= \frac{1}{4} \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(12n+7-12n-8+6+\frac{4}{n} \right)\\
 &= \frac{5}{4}
\end{align*}

Since $p > 1$, by Raabe's test series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n!e^n}{n^{n+\frac{7}{4}}}$ converges. By limit comparison test, original series then also converges.

Now, I'm not a mathematician - I'm currently learning analysis by myself and I welcome any feedback/criticism so that I can improve. Thanks!

**EDIT:** I now realize that instead of applying L'Hôpital's rule second time, I could have used Taylor series expansion for $\ln$ there. But still, it seems over-complicated.

Comment: $(2n)!! = 2^n n!$, not $2^n n^n$.

Comment: You're right. I did it on paper but mixed things up while writing it here. Thanks for the correction, I'll edit original post.

Comment: Also, Stirling's approximation to the factorial is a faster method.

Comment: Ahh, that makes it trivial! P-series with exponent greater than 1 :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use comparison limit test again with the series $\sum \frac {1}{n^{\frac 5 4}}$ and Stirling's approximation:

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{n!e^n}{n^{n+\frac{7}{4}}}\right) {n^{\frac 5 4}} & = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{2πn} \left(\frac n e \right)^n \left( \frac {e^n}{n^n \sqrt n} \right)  \\
& = \sqrt{2π}
\end{align}$$